# PHP: Is the $_FILES ['tmp_name'] unique?

Tags: php, upload

I've created my first site with an image uploading feature and this just crossed my mind. Is `['tmp_name']` in `$_FILES` a unique value like in `uniqid()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unique in that you can never have two files with the same name at any given time. However since the files are temporary they will most likely be deleted shortly after their creation, so the filenames free up again.

Comment: `However since the files are temporary they will most likely be deleted shortly after their creation` - [from the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php): `The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.`

Comment: I was talking about temporary files in general, but thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 4):

It's unique for the time being. As soon as you delete it (it should be deleted automatically when the script finishes) some file may and eventually will get the same name. [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) doesn't say that `tmp_name` is unique, so simplified answer is **no**, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP generates this to uniquely name an uploaded file. 
You can't guarantee the file will stay around forever depending on where it's stored to. Often it's /var/tmp